# qt : Transparent QWidget on Maya Viewport

Tags: qt, transparent, viewport, maya

[image]

I made a custom window for maya. It contains Maya's modelEditor, so I can use viewport control on my custom window. So I tried to leave QLabel on modelEditor as a HUD. But as you see, QLabel doesn't work it's transparency. I hope to let them have their transparency. Maya openGL doesn't treat well (maybe I think). Can I make a detour the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some `QWidget` containing a `QLabel`, then you will have access to usefull things about your widget transparency, such as :

```
setWindowOpacity(0.85);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

You can also try the [stylesheet](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-examples.html) preferences about transparency.

I hope it will help !